# JavaParser reading a src directory

Tags: java, javaparser

I've been using a `CompilationUnit` to parse Java files but now I'd like to parse all files within a directory.

I've tried the following however the compilation size is calculated as 0 when I expect it to be the number of Java files within the specified directory.

```
Path pathToSource = Paths.get("resources/src");
SourceRoot sourceRoot = new SourceRoot(pathToSource);
List<CompilationUnit> compilations = sourceRoot.getCompilationUnits();
```

Following the JavaDoc - https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.javaparser/javaparser-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to add all the compilation units manually, or just call `tryToParse()` on the `sourceRoot`.

With this small modification, it found (almost*) all .java files below the SourceRoot.

```
Path pathToSource = Paths.get("resources/src");
SourceRoot sourceRoot = new SourceRoot(pathToSource);
sourceRoot.tryToParse();
List<CompilationUnit> compilations = sourceRoot.getCompilationUnits();
```

(* it did not support java modules, so it failed to parse my `module-info.java`).

Answer (score 0):

The pathToSource variable must refer to the root directory which corresponds to **the root of the package structure** of the source files it contains.
For example, in a classic maven project, this variable should be initialized with the src/main/java directory.